# Insertar un rango de celdas de una hoja de cálculo de Google en un correo mediante Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, gmail

Necesito insertar un rango de celdas en un correo de gmail para posteriormente enviarlo a través de un código de Google App Script. No he logrado copiar el rango de manera que este mantenga su formato dentro del correo (principalmente las celdas combinadas se separan y pierden su formato). ¿Existe alguna manera de copiar mediante un código el rango e insertarlo en el correo manteniendo su formato?. (Da lo mismo si es una imagen una tabla, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script no incluye una clase o método que convierta un rango con formato a HTML pero sí con varios métodos que permiten identificar muchas de las características para luego reproducir el formato.

Existe [un proyecto en GitHub](https://github.com/mogsdad/SheetConverter) que se ha quedado atrás en relación a los métodos que se han agregado desde que se actualizó por última vez, pero que te podría ser de utilidad para empezar, pero si te da lo mismo cómo se presenta, quizás lo más práctico es que lo envíes como archivo adjunto.